# inserting date column throwing java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Tags: java, oracle, date, spring-integration, sqlexception

I have a table with number, varchar2 and Date columns. I am trying to insert data into this table in which number and date (dd-MMM-yy) fields are fetched from another table.

Table structure:

```
ID NOT NULL NUMBER(11)  
SOURCEID VARCHAR2(20)
MESSAGE VARCHAR2(250)  
CODE VARCHAR2(20)  
LSTUPDT DATE
```

Java Pojo:

```
int id;  
String sourceId;
String message;  
String code;  
Date lastUpdDate;
```

Have a plain insert statement in Sprint Integration xml file.

Problem is the Date field. If I remove the date, records are inserted fine. 
I tried to use Date, Timestamp, LocalDate in my pojo and nothing worked. Please advice.

```
<integration:channel id="retrieveIdDetailsRequestChannel" />
            <integration:channel id="retrieveIdDetailsReplyChannel" />
            <integration:channel id="insertIdDetailsRequestChannel" />

            <integration:gateway id="retrieveService" service-interface="com.test.RetrieveIdDetailService">
                <integration:method name="retrieveIds" 
                    request-channel="retrieveIdDetailsRequestChannel"
                    reply-channel="retrieveIdDetailsReplyChannel"
                    request-timeout="5000"
                    reply-timeout="5000"/>
                <integration:method name="insertIdExternalStatus"
                    request-channel="insertIdDetailsRequestChannel"
                    request-timeout="5000"
                    reply-timeout="5000"/>
            </integration:gateway>
    <int-jdbc:outbound-gateway data-source="db"
                update="insert into table_test values (:Id, :sourceId, :Message, :Code, :lstupdt)"
                request-channel="insertIdDetailsRequestChannel"
                reply-channel="nullChannel"
                request-sql-parameter-source-factory="parameterSourceFactory"/> 

            <bean id="parameterSourceFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
                <property name="parameterExpressions">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="Id"     value="payload.getId()" />
                        <entry key="sourceId"   value="payload.getSourceId()" />
                        <entry key="Message"    value="payload.getMessage()" />
                        <entry key="Code"   value="payload.getCode()" />
                        <entry key="lstupdt"    value="payload.getLastUpdatedDate()" />
                    </map>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </beans>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into table_test values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:894)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageHandler.executeUpdateQuery(JdbcMessageHandler.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(JdbcOutboundGateway.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:135)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:375)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:477)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:429)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:420)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.insertIdExternalStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.fis.mtr.Fima2Service.getFimaTrades(Fima2Service.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10495)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9974)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10799)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10776)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:241)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:365)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:454)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:238)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.setValues(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:244)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:627)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: Why don't you show the StackTrace on the matter and configuration?

Comment: Stacktrace didn't help much

Comment: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into table_test values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Comment: OK. How would you like to get a help from us if you don't answer positive to our requests? I might stop looking to your questions here and just always request to close them. We have some other work to do rather than arguing with you about important information. Thanks for understanding

Comment: That isn't readable from comments. Consider to edit your question and study how to represent the code here on SO. Please, respect our time and intention to help you to solve the problem. Nevertheless I think this is what you need there: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4291

Comment: Very Sorry. I am relatively new to posting questions and comments. I was trying to copy the entire stack trace, but it was allowing me to copy due to limited chars. I am copying the configuration part now.

Comment: Sorry for not posting things clearly. I have made things look better than before.

Comment: Good. Much better now. Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind to turn on `TRACE` logging level for the `org.springframework.jdbc.core` category? I'm interested in the message like: `Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index...`  from the `StatementCreatorUtils` class

Comment: Thank you..! I am looking at the Jira link you provided. Will update if I find something that works for me.

Comment: Sure will do and update the latest stack trace

Comment: "insert into table_test values (:Id, :sourceId, :Message, :Code, :lstupdt)" doesn't match your table description.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to check this. I reduced the actual table details here to make my post simple.

Comment: Is your `Date` a `java.sql.Date`?